# C# - Linq optimize code with List and Where clause

Tags: c#, performance, linq, optimization

I have a following code:

```
        var tempResults = new Dictionary<Record, List<Record>>();            
        errors = new List<Record>();
        foreach (Record record in diag)
        {
            var code = Convert.ToInt16(Regex.Split(record.Line, @"\s{1,}")[4], 16);                
            var cond = codes.Where(x => x.Value == code && x.Active).FirstOrDefault();
            if (cond == null)
            {
                errors.Add(record);
                continue;
            }

            var min = record.Datetime.AddSeconds(downDiff);
            var max = record.Datetime.AddSeconds(upDiff);

            //PROBLEM PART - It takes around 4,5ms
            var possibleResults = cas.Where(x => x.Datetime >= min && x.Datetime <= max).ToList();

            if (possibleResults.Count == 0)
                errors.Add(record);
            else
            {                    
                if (!CompareCond(record, possibleResults, cond, ref tempResults, false))
                {                        
                        errors.Add(record);
                }
            }
        }
```

variable diag is List of Record

variable cas is List of Record with around 50k items.

The problem is that it's too slowly. The part with the first where clause needs around 4,6599ms, e.g. for 3000 records in List diag it makes 3000*4,6599 = 14 seconds. Is there any option to optimize the code?

Comment: You could prefilter `codes` outside the forEach loop to only contain items that are active. This would reduce the number you'd have to search through inside your loop.

Comment: Yes, that's true, thank you for the notice. I have already done it. Now, it is a bit better but the main problem is still the where clause with time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can speed up that specific statement you emphasized

```
cas.Where(x => x.Datetime >= min && x.Datetime <= max).ToList();
```

With binary search over `cas` list. First pre-sort `cas` by `Datetime`:

```
cas.Sort((a,b) => a.Datetime.CompareTo(b.Datetime));
```

Then create comparer for `Record` which will compare only `Datetime` properties (implementation assumes there are no null records in the list):

```
private class RecordDateComparer : IComparer<Record> {
    public int Compare(Record x, Record y) {
        return x.Datetime.CompareTo(y.Datetime);
    }
}
```

Then you can translate your `Where` clause like this:

```
var index = cas.BinarySearch(new Record { Datetime = min }, new RecordDateComparer());
if (index < 0)
    index = ~index;
var possibleResults = new List<Record>();    
// go backwards, for duplicates            
for (int i = index - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var res = cas[i];
    if (res.Datetime <= max && res.Datetime >= min)
        possibleResults.Add(res);
    else break;
}
// go forward until item bigger than max is found
for (int i = index; i < cas.Count; i++) {
    var res = cas[i];
    if (res.Datetime <= max &&res.Datetime >= min)
        possibleResults.Add(res);
    else break;
}
```

Idea is to find first record with `Datetime` equal or greater to your `min`, with `BinarySearch`. If exact match is found - it returns index of matched element. If not found - it returns negative value, which can be translated to the index of first element greater than target with `~index` operation.

When we found that element, we can just go forward the list and grab items until we find item with `Datetime` greater than max (because list is sorted). We need to go a little backwards also, because if there are duplicates - binary search will not necessary return the first one, so we need to go backwards for potential duplicates.

Additional improvements might include:

- Putting active codes in a `Dictionary` (keyed by `Value`) outside of for loop, and thus replacing codes `Where` search with `Dictionary.ContainsKey`.
- As suggested in comments by @Digitalsa1nt - parallelize foreach loop, using `Parallel.For`, PLINQ, or any similar techniques. It's a perfect case for parallelization, because loop contains only CPU bound work. You need to make a little adjustments to make it thread-safe of course, such as using thread-safe collection for `errors` (or locking around adding to it).

Comment: Thank you! It's great. 4,5 ms was decreased to around 0,5ms and it's much better. This is the first time I have heard of BinarySearch, good to know it. :)

Comment: @FilipProcházka so that's fast enough or you want even faster? :)

Comment: It's enough. :) But if there is another option to optimize it and you have time to describe/explain how to do it I like to learn them. :) Or just tell me keywords what I should search for and I'll try to learn/do them myself.

Comment: @FilipProcházka I have a _feeling_ it can be faster, but cannot provide more guidance with just code, without the goal of that code. But you can move active codes out of the loop and put into `HashSet`. If you have a lot of codes - it might speed up things a bit. But otherwise I have no more ideas.

Comment: @Evk would you ever consider a PLinq implementation here, to perform the task in parallel or would that not be possible?

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt yes actually this is a perfect case for parallization. Almost no mutable shared state, CPU bound work.

Comment: @FilipProcházka there is a good advice above - you can speed this even more by parallelizing the loop .

Comment: Parallelizing, of course! It should cross my mind. I'm idiot. Thank you all. Next week I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding [AsNoTracking](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/entity-framework-and-asnotracking/) in the list

The `AsNoTracking` method can save both execution times and memory usage. Applying this option really becomes important when we retrieve a large amount of data from the database.

```
var possibleResults = cas.Where(x => x.Datetime >= min && x.Datetime <= max).AsNoTracking().ToList(); //around 4,6599ms
```

Comment: Unfortunately, It has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

There a few improvements you can make here.
It might only be a minor performance increase but you should try using groupby instead of where in this circumstance.

So instead you should have something like this:

```
cas.GroupBy(x => x.DateTime >= min && x.DateTime <= max).Select(h => h.Key == true);
```

This ussually works for seaching through lists for distinct values, but in you case I'm unsure if it will provide you any benefit when using a clause.

Also a few other things you can do throughout you code:

- Avoid using ToList when possible and stick to IEnumerable. ToList performs an eager evaluation which is probably causing a lot of slowdown in your query.
- use .Any() instead of Count when checking if values exist (This only applies if the list is IEnumerable)